# Can't Declare a Variable Char[]

Tags: c++

```
struct Movie
{
    char* date;
    char* title;
    char* rating;
    int runtime;
};

typedef Movie* moviePtr;
moviePtr tempDB;

bool doStuff()
{
//... snip .,,
    tempDB = new Movie[tempC];
    int i;

    ifs >> temp;
    while(ifs.good() && i < tempC)
    {
        tempDB[i].date = new char[strlen(temp)+1];
        strcpy(tempDB[i].date, temp);
//... snip ...

}
```

When I run that, I get a segmentation fault (on line tempDB[i].date = new char[strlen(temp)+1]; I debugged it)

tempC is how big the array should be, read from the file.

What have I done wrong :(

Comment: Why aren't you using `std::string` and `std::vector`?

Comment: We can't use them, my prof. said so :( I've tried in the past.

Comment: Strings makes life so much easier!!!

Comment: What type is `temp`?  You perhaps should try breaking up that expression to determine if it's the `strlen(temp)` call that's crashing.

Comment: Kindly tell your professor he's an idiot. Your best bet would be to re-make a simple string and vector class yourself and use those. You should always separate resource usage from resource management. (Right now you're trying to do both.) It's not only easier, but safer, cleaner, and more elegant.

Comment: @Johnny Consider writing your own naive string and vector implementations then. They're not too difficult, they're reusable, and you'll probably learn a thing or two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not initialize i to 0, or whatever you want to start indexing at.

Another note, in case of errors like seg-fault use Valgrind [valgrind.org] -- it helps spot the error in seconds. In your case an out of index memory access -- these are things Valgrind specializes in detecting.

Answer (score 2):

You never initialize `i` so at the time you check it for `i < tempC` and then use it for `tempDB[i]`, `i` could be worth **anything at all** -- say `-929373`, leading to addressing completely outside of your process boundaries (if you're lucky, because that will at least immediately produce an error -- if you're unlucky you'll end up destroying data randomly and producing horrible, impossible-to-debug mistakes at some much later point).

Use `int i = 0;` instead, to avoid the curse of the uninitialized variable!-)